# Is there any simple way to replicate sections in CiviMail message templates?

Tags: civimail, templates

Is there any simple way to replicate sections of email templates (for example, a section corresponding to one story) without having to copy and paste and guard to catch all the tables and other elements in the section?

MailChimp solves it with a property repeatable http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/

Answer (score 2):

At this year's Denver sprint or con, Veda consulting demoed a working extension. The core stuff is supported by the upstream editor itself, so I don't think any smarty hacks were required. That's the limit of my knowledge though — I wasn't there. Hopefully we'll get to see it for 4.7 if not before.

Here is the code:
https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.quickbulkemail

It also seems to simplify bulk mailing, but does not appear to be compatible with 4.6.

In 2016, they developed an extension to integrate mosaico.io into civicrm. See more about it here: https://civicrm.org/blogs/parvez/a-new-beginning-for-civimail%E2%80%A6

Comment: I was at the code sprint and saw this demo.  It fixes a lot of issues with CiviMail, but unfortunately this isn't one of them - this very issue came up.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in Smarty via either the "assign" or "capture" custom functions. Check:

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.builtin.functions.tpl#language.function.capture

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.assign

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean but I do not see that this is a solution for an end user. May be a first approach to improve CiviMail in this way or develop a specific extension?

Comment: yes, agreed. civimail does not have a good template editor like mailchimp and adding one would be a great first step. I think making the template editor programmable, would be the next step.